# Redux: useSelector value is undefined despite it appearing in devTools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to setup a redux environment and I'm stumped as to why I am having this behavior.

**I have my root state here on my reducer:**

```
export type RootState = {
  counter: number;
};
const initialState: RootState = { counter: 0 };

const staticLesson = (state = initialState, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return state.counter + 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default staticLesson;
```

**I then combine it here:**

```
import staticLesson from "./staticLesson/index";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  staticLesson,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**I wrap my App with the Provider:**

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./redux/reducers";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools());

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**Yet, when I try to log it in my component, the value is undefined.**

```
const Component = () => {
  const staticLesson = useSelector((state: RootState) => state);   
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  console.log("counter", staticLesson.counter); <-- logs undefined

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

What I don't understand is why if I *just log* `staticLesson`, it appears as expected in my console. But if I try to access the value on the object, instead of getting the value `0` for my counter ... I get `undefined`. `staticLesson` is showing up in my devTools, it's there ... I'm stumped, what am i messing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you should be returning the `staticLesson` property from the state in your `useSelector` call. In `useSelector` you're returning the *entire* state. So it should be:

```
const staticLesson = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.staticLesson);
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks that did it. Such a small little thing to miss